# Using babel/i18n with webapp2 and deferred tasks in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, internationalization, webapp2, babeljs

I have a relatively expensive email-a-set-of-people tasks for which I am trying to use the "deferred" library in Google AppEngine. I'd like to send the handler just the list of recipients and some details, and have the handler format the emails to the correct language for each person. I'm using Babel.

If I do this without deferring, works great - the translations for the content load and all is good. But if I defer and move the fetching of the content to the handler, the i18n library isn't loaded properly - i18n.get_i18n().translations is a NullTranslations object. So the deferred task handler apparently don't get the context when it kicks off - is there a way to intialize i18n to get it to reload properly? Or some way to tell the AppEngine to preserve some context?

thanks!

Comment: We need to see some code to help you.  It seems that i18n shouldn't care whether it is being called from a handler or a deferred task.  How are you passing the locale to the deferred task?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. If I use the regular task queue instead of the deferred library, it works fine. The 'deferred' library is supposed to just be a wrapper around the task queue system, but it apparently acts differently to the i18n libray. i18n does want the 'request' object; maybe the deferred handler does something weird with it. No matter - using the queue directly is almost as easy.